# Activity life cycle with fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have  1 Activity 1 fragment and 2 screens ...

the Activity has a first Screen

```
setcontentview(R.layout.main)
```

i am using `Actionbar menu` to go to second screen(fragment using fragment Manager)

the fragment has a Second Screen

when i close the fragment,its come to the first Screen
but none of the method is called ,so i could not do some changes  in activity screen

I have tried in `onCreate(),onStart(),onResume().`

i have tried with in oncreate

```
if (savedInstanceState==null)

    {
       //my functions

    }
```

Comment: refer this - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

Comment: show how do you replace a new `Fragment`

Answer (score 0):

The deal is that `Fragment`'s lifecycle callbacks differs of `Activity`'s ones. For your particular issue you may try to use to override `onViewStateRestored` method of your `Fragment` or `onCreateView` depends on how you manage your fragments when performing fragment transaction.

Answer (score 0):

i have found answer myself

i called those methods when fragments when into pause state

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
   getActivity().somefunctions();
}
```